# Commenting instead of answering

Tags: support

Ok, bear with me here - I'm new to StackExchange as a whole.

First off, am I using the meta site correctly by posting this question here rather than on the main site? If not, let me know how/where I should have posted it.

In [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/1344/306), I posted an "[answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/1566/306)", even though I felt I should probably post a "comment". Sure enough, someone pointed out that I should have commented rather than answered. Perfectly fair, but... How does one comment? I can't seem to find any way to comment on a question. Do I need more reputation to be able to comment?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hi and welcome to SFSE !

Well, this is how comments work:

- you need 50 rep to comment globally (e.g. on every answer or comment)
- you can always comment on your own questions and answers and/or answers to your questions.

You can read it here:

[How does comment voting and flagging work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17364/how-do-comment-voting-and-flagging-work)

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment

As for the your comment, I converted it to a comment.

Answer (score 2):

It does seem a little weird to be able to write an answer before you can comment. This is a comment for instance -- it doesn't seem to warrant it's own question - but I want to bolster the questioners stance... Most of what I want to do is comment, so it's frustrating...

Comment: I'd say ... comment as an answer but try to do it a bit more extensively. And .. ignore the comments and responses you'll get on that for doing so. You're new and your options are limited. Either the comment-ish answer is good enough for an answer and it'll stay, or a moderator may convert it into a comment for you. That is definitely the way I handle these.   Thank you for contributing!

Comment: @Adrian Cotter I agree that it seems a bit odd not to be able to comment when you can already post questions or answers and I personally would agree with the bar being lower on being able to post a comment. Now I believe that you will be able to comment as you have got enough rep.

Comment: cheers guys. looks like I now do have the rep :) 
which now I think will remove that barrier from contributing a little more!